# Is it a good practice to create an object of a controller in another controller following MVC in PHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, methods, controller

We all (most of us) know that controller's job is to handle the request made by client (e.g. web browser), get the model, render the view.

My senior developer has 20 years experience, grown up with native PHP, unlike me 4 years experience, grown up with PHP MVC frameworks. I saw my senior developer creates an object of a controller in another controller's action function because he wants to use the same business logic as below sample.

```
class FooController extend Controller {

     public function view($id) {

         // Business logic goes here...

         // Pseudo code
         // If request comes from BarController
         // Render no layout, only view template.


         // If request comes from browser
         // Render view template with layout.
     }
}

class BarController extends Controller {

     public function viewFoo($id) {

          // Create an object of FooController so that we can reuse the business logic of the view function.
          $foo = new FooController();
          $foo_view = $foo->view($id);

          // Render $foo_view template.
     }
}
```

Is it a good practice to create an object of a controller (in this case `FooController`) in another controller (in this case in `BarController::viewFoo($id)` ), following MVC design pattern?

Comment: No. Also, what you are describing there is **not** MVC.

Comment: @tereško I agree with you. I would not create an object of a controller (which is meant to handle the user request), and would not call the controller's action function to reuse the business logic in that action function. Rather I would place the business logic in a model and in any controller I rather create an object of that model and call that model's function where the business logic lives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This practice may be ok in some situations but in general it's a sign of problems.

According to some people, reusable business logic doesn't belong in the controller. Instead they recommend some variation of "fat model skinny controller" (put these terms in an internet search engine). Controllers should be really simple, and the reusable logic should be in the model layer, or in a separate services layer.

Given that, most people would assume that controllers are not reused like this. This makes the application brittle: Imagine someone changing the reused controller or the view it renders: they won't know they have to test this unrelated part of the application.

Comment: I agree with you. When my senior developer said "I have 20 years pure PHP experience. You have least experience. That's why you are shocked when you see the way I program.", I start to doubt about his 20 years experience with the new coming of MVC frameworks, OOP, program to an interface not implementation ect.